# How can I change the names of all tables to uppercase?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

User created one database, for example TestDb.

Within this database the user created 30 tables, with the table name in lower case letters `(Eg:Employee)`.

Is it possible to change the tables names to upper case `(eg:EMPLOYEE)` in `SQL Server 2008 R2`?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the server collation case sensitive ? If not then, what is the problem you are facing so that you need to rename all the tables to UPPER case ?

Answer (score 3):

To rename table names in UPPER Case:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename '
+ '''' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ''', '
+ '''' + UPPER(TABLE_NAME) + ''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' +
QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
```

To rename Columns names in UPPER Case:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + '.' + 
COLUMN_NAME + ''', ''' +
UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) + ''',''COLUMN'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']'),
'isMSShipped') = 0
```

Result generated by above commands can run on query window to rename table name or column name in upper case respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 'exec sp_rename '
+ '''' + QuoteName(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QuoteName(TABLE_NAME) + ''', '
+ '''' + Upper(TABLE_NAME) + ''''
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Run This Script and you will get answer.Copy columns and run it. Now Table name will Changed.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't rely on [the unreliable `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views), and also handles poorly named objects (such as `my'table`) - but assumes you don't have otherwise poorly named objects (such as `my[table]`):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
EXEC sp_rename N''' 
  + s.name 
  + '.' + REPLACE(t.name, '''', '''''') + ''',N''' 
  + UPPER(REPLACE(t.name, '''', '''''')) + ''',N''OBJECT'';'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```